# PHP Caching with APC

Tags: php, caching, apc

Let's say I cache data in a PHP file in PHP array like this:

/cache.php

```
<?php return (object) array(
    'key' => 'value',
);
```

And I include the cache file like this:

```
<?php
$cache = include 'cache.php';
```

Now, the question is will the cache file be automatically cached by APC in the memory? I mean as a typical opcode cache, as all .php files.

If I store the data differently for example in JSON format (cache.json), the data will not be automatically cached by APC?

Would `apc_store` be faster/preferable?

Answer (score 10):

Don't mix APC's caching abilities with its ability to optimize intermediate code and cache compiled code. APC provides 2 different things:

1. It gives a handy method of caching data structures (objects,
   arrays etc), so that you can store/get them with apc_store and
   apc_fetch
2. It keeps a compiled version of your scripts so that the
   next time they run, they run faster

Let's see an example for (1): Suppose you have a data structure which takes 1 second to calculate:

```
function calculate_array() {
    sleep(1);
    return array('foo' => 'bar');
}
$data = calculate_array();
```

You can store its output so that you don't have to call the slow calculate_array() again:

```
function calculate_array() {
    sleep(1);
    return array('foo' => 'bar');
}
if (!apc_exists('key1')) {
    $data = calculate_array();
    apc_store('key1', $data);
} else {
    $data = apc_fetch('key1');
}
```

which will be considerably faster, much less than the original 1 second.

Now, for (2) above: having APC will not make your program run faster than 1 second, which is the time that calculate_array() needs. However, if your file additionally needed (say) 100 milliseconds to initialize and execute, simply having enabled APC will make it need (approx) 20 millisecond. So you have an 80% increase in initialization/preparation time. This can make quite a difference in production systems, so simply installing APC can have a noticeable positive impact on your script's performance, even if you never explicitly call any of its functions

Comment: So the cache.php would be opcode compiled? But apc_store would be still better and faster?

Comment: Yes, the *file* it will be opcode compiled. apc_store does something different, it stores structures. These are 2 different things for 2 different needs. I'll update my answer with more details

Comment: I don't like the first sentence: APC does not compile op-codes, thats what the engine is for. APC provides a byte-code (opcode-/system-cache). However, it's true, that it is not the same, as the variable-cache (user-cache), but at the end they behave very similar, except that the first one is used by the extension itself (implict) and the second one is used by userland code (explicit). As a sidenote: Datastructures cannot "calculate", they just exists ;) So your example is misleading too.

Comment: @KingCrunch: you are correct, very bad terminology on my side, I'll update my answer

Comment: But you store the output in the cache.php, that's why it is called "cache.php"

Comment: In this case, I'm positive that apc_store will be faster than putting the code in a file

Comment: @periklis Can you provide some numbers :) I can imagine, that there is really a difference (pro-`apc_store`), but I fear, that for a single file compared to a single `apc_fetch()` it is not measurable... Would be interesting anyway

Comment: @KingCrunch: I'm actually intrigued to try this out, it would be an interesting benchmark to tun - I'll get back with some actualy data

Answer (score 2):

If you are just storing static data (as in your example), it would be preferable to use `apc_store`.

The reasoning behind this is not so much whether the opcode cache is faster or slower, but the fact you are using `include` to fetch static data into scope.

Even with an opcode cache, the file will still be checked for consistency on each execution. PHP will not have to parse the contents, but it will have to check whether the file exists, and that it hasn't changed since the opcode cache was created. Filesystem checks are resource expensive, even if it is only to `stat` a file.

Therefore, of the two approaches I would use `apc_store` to remove the filesystem checks completely.

Comment: You can disable the `stat`-call with http://php.net/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat

Comment: That is true, but the cache must then be manually flushed in order to reflect changes made to the file. There is a tendency for people to forget this when making updates, particularly when there are lots of files being changed.

Comment: This is, what deploy-scripts are invented for ;)

Comment: A person still has to write the deploy script, usually the same person who forgets about the config file being changed :)

Comment: And the same person, that forgot to switch the lights off ... We can imagine many cases, where everything can go horrible wrong... But to be realistic: a) The same dude, that set `stat=0` changes the deploy script and b) even if not, someone will notice it and change the script. After this it will clear the cache for the next 150 years. The one time, where someone forgot it, will also not lead to a black hole under your servers. I would clean the cache anyway (as essential part of every deployment), independent whether `stat` is off, or not ;) And not only APC

Comment: Even so, if using `include` with `stat=0` you must flush the whole cache and / or restart the server. That seems like a pretty serious anti-pattern right there.

Comment: The cache with the outdated cached data also has to be flushed - this is no difference to using the opcode cache.

Comment: There is a difference @Sven. If you don't explicitly use `apc_delete_file()` you have to clear all the opcode caches on the server; not just the file you have updated. The alternative is using `apc_clear_cache()` (which behaves differently with different CGI implementations) or hope restarting the server flushes it (again, restarting does not completely guarantee a cache flush, check the documentation). My argument is that if you must use an `apc_()` function to clear the opcode cache anyway, why not eliminate potential points of failure and use `apc_store()` to begin with?

Comment: @plasmid87 You have to clear caches on deployment anyway ... No matter which cache, or why. Last one ("why") is easy: You _must_ assume, that it is outdated. Remember, that for every call to a `apc_*()`-function you need special handling for development setups, because developing with `apc` isn't useful. This said: There is no reasonable downside in using the file-cache to cache the configuration-_file_. Oh, and btw: Even with `stat=1` it only affects one file ;) (the "normal" php files would be affected anyway).

Comment: @KingCrunch It's a moot point that depends entirely on the server environment and demand. Using `stat=0` isn't an issue for smaller installations where restarting is quick and impact minimal. Unfortunately, on larger installations where many applications are running, clearing the entire cache via restart isn't a very appealing option. I mostly use abstracted drivers, which allows the use of APC, memcache, etc. interchangeably in different environments. This limits the development benefits of using `include` to fetch cached information, but I can see a use-case for it when writing naked PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other answer I would use the array-file-solution (the first one)

```
<?php return (object) array(
    'key' => 'value',
);
```

The reason is, that with both solutions you are on the right side, but when you let the caching up to APC itself you don't have to juggle around with the `apc_*()`-functions. You simply include and use it. When you set

```
apc.stat = 0
```

you avoid the `stat`-calls on every include too. This is useful for production, but remember to clear the system-cache on every deployment.

http://php.net/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat

Oh, not to forget: With the file-approach it works even without APC. Useful for the development setup, where you usually shouldn't use any caching.

Comment: That's interesting, I wouldn't expect this to be faster than apc_fetch/apc_store

Comment: I don't think it's faster either, but I think the difference is soooo much negligable ;)

Comment: I originally asked this question because I too think that the difference is negligible, but using files: (1) you don't write an additional code; (2) even if you don't have APC it is still cached